# Value of the series with following terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

A sequence $x_n$ is defined as $x_{k+1}=x_k^2+x_k$ and $x_1=\frac{1}{2}$
Let:

$$S_n=\left[\frac{1}{x_1+1}+\frac{1}{x_2+1}+\frac{1}{x_3+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_n+1}\right]$$

where $[\cdot]$ denotes greatest integer function. What is value of $S_{100}$?

By manipulating the definition of series i deduced that $x_k+1=\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}$.
So the series becomes $\left[\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k}{x_{k+1}}\right]$. But what to do after that?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention it. I have edited my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $(x_n)_n$ is increasing and cannot be bounded so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=+\infty$.
Also,
$$\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{x_n}-\frac{1}{x_n+1}$$ hence
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+x_k}=\frac{1}{x_1}-\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}=2-\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}$$
Now, $x_1=3/4$ and $x_2>1$ hence for $n\ge1$ we have $x_{n+1}>1$, and consequently
$$\forall\,n\ge1,\qquad 2>2-\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}>1$$
Thus $\left[2-\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}\right]=1$ for every $n\ge1$. In particular, $S_{100}=1$.